# How do I show $x^2+1$ is reducible or irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_7$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

How do I show $x^2 + 1$ is reducible or irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_7$? Is there a standardized procedure to check ?

Thanks

Comment: For a quadratic or cubic polynomial, irreducibility is equivalent to having no roots in the base field. No “$i$” in $\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z$? Irreducible!

Comment: It is irreducible for any prime p = 3 (mod 4).

Answer (score 1):

Since $a^6\equiv 1\pmod 7$ for any $a$ not divisible by $7$, then if $-1$ is a square modulo $7$ then $(-1)^3\equiv 1\pmod 7$. We can see it is not.

More generally, the answer is to use various forms of quadratic reciprocity to determine if $x^2+n$ is irreducible modulo $p$.

Comment: In this particular case, much easier to test the seven elements to see whether any of them satisfies $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. It makes sense. but would this method work for any other polynomial. in example let say we have x^3+x+1 in Z2 how would I use the modulo method

Comment: Easier than just cubing $(-1)$? @Lubin :)

Comment: The general question is non-trivial. If $p$ is prime and $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ then $f(x)$ is prime if $f(x)\mid x^{p^n}-x$ and relatively prime with other $x^{p^d}-x$, with $d\mid n$.

Comment: In the case of $x^3+x+1$ over the field with two elements, nothing makes it zero, so the polynomial is irreducible. The method fails for polynomials of degree $\ge4$, though, so don’t be misled.

Comment: great, thanks Thomas and Lubin

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, as mentioned in comments, the first way I would think:

We will look at $x^2+1$ over $\Bbb F_7$. It is irreducible if it has no roots in the field $\Bbb F_7$. Now we can see that a root will have $x^2=-1\equiv 6\pmod 7$

$1^2=1$, $2^2=4$, $3^2\equiv 2\pmod 7$, $4^2\equiv 2\pmod 7$, $5^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 7$, $6^2\equiv 1\pmod 7$, $7^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 7$. Hence $x^2$ cannot equal $6\pmod 7$, and no root is present in $\Bbb F_7$.